# Move parameter in Clojure function

Tags: clojure

I'm working on [4clojure](http://www.4clojure.com) problem 29 : ["Get the Caps"](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/29)

```
(= (__ "HeLlO, WoRlD!") "HLOWRD")
```

I've written a solution in the REPL:

```
user=> (apply str (filter (fn [foo] (some #(= % foo) 
         (map char (range 65 91)))) "AbC"))
"AC"
```

But as you can see my parameter "AbC" is nested two parentheses in. How would I move my parameter to the outside so I can use it in the 4clojure test? Have I approached the problem in the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to move the a parameter to the outside, you can just use the same technique you used to create the filtering function, that is, with `fn`:

```
(fn [string] 
  (apply str 
    (filter 
      (fn [foo] (some #(= % foo) (map char (range 65 91)))) 
      string)))
```

As an example of this, the following two statements are the same:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
((fn [n] (+ 1 2 n)) 3)
```

However, to actually answer your question, you could use [`comp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp) ("compose") and [`partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partial) to move the parameter to allow [eta conversion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion) (that is the technical name for the last part of the manipulation you are attempting to do):

```
(comp (partial apply str)
      (partial filter (fn [foo] (some #(= % foo) 
                                       (map char (range 65 91))))))
```

This expression is now a function that takes a string, filters the capital letters and then converts it back to a string (notices that `comp` applies functions from right to left).

(NB, that last expression probably isn't very idiomatic Clojure; the first method, or one of the suggestions of others, is better.)

Comment: Thanks Huon. I needed to use the **comp** approach to get my solution into 4clojure's "quiz" system. Other solutions used an **apply str** on a regex (**re-seq**), but that's ok - it's reinforced two concepts - comp & re-seq.

Comment: @SoniaHamilton, it's very impolite to use someone's real name if they are posting under a pseudonym (even if their real name is associated with that pseudonym!). But good to hear :)

Comment: Also, @SoniaHamilton, you *can* use the anonymous function syntax with `fn` on 4clojure.com: `(fn [x] (* 2 x))` is a working solution for [problem 15](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/15).

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a function as a solution. Something like:

```
(fn [text] 
    (apply str (filter (fn [foo] (some #(= % foo) 
                                        (map char (range 65 91)))) 
                       text)))
```

Also you can use [Character.isUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) to filter all upper case chars: `(filter (fn [ch] (Character/isUpperCase ch) text)`

Comment: Thanks Nikita. **dbaupp**'s solution was more helpful - in the 4clojure "quiz" the text is outside any brackets, so making it into a fn doesn't work...

Comment: @SoniaHamilton It does work. I solved the same task with `fn`: `(fn [text] (apply str (filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) text)))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with 4Clojure, but if it's allowed, you could use `clojure.string/replace`.

The following should do the trick:

```
(fn [s] (clojure.string/replace s #"[^A-Z]" ""))
```

Everything that isn't in the range A to Z is replaced with the empty string.